# NodeJS redirect site after render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Right now I'm developing a simple NodeJS and Express app that receives some data, makes a series of 'POST' calls, and then redirects to another site. The app should have a front view of a simple loading screen, and after the last 'POST' is done, should redirect you to an external site.

The problem I'm facing is the following:

I have this code here that does all the stuff it needs to do in the logic part.

```
router.get('/:data', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' })

   /**
   * Decodes a JWT token to retrieve the data
   * @param {string} token 
   */
  function decodeJWT(token) {
    let base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    let base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
    let decodedData = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(base64, 'base64').toString('binary'));

    return decodedData;
  }

  try {
    var data = decodeJWT(req.params.data);
    let brandId = data['payload']['data']['brandId'] || null;
    let deviceId = data['payload']['data']['deviceId'] || null;
    let products = data['payload']['data']['products'] || null;

    let brand = brands[brandId];
    let postUrl = brand['postUrl'];

    if (products && products.length > 0) {
      let series = [];

      products.forEach((product, index) => {
        series.push(function (callback) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            let credentials = '';
            credentials += 'username=' + encodeURIComponent('username');
            credentials += '&password=' + encodeURIComponent('password');

            axios.post('url', credentials)
              .then(response => {   
                if (index + 1 === products.length) {
                  res.redirect(brand['url']);
                  res.end()
                } else {
                  callback(null, (products.length - index) * 100)
                }
              })
              .catch(e => console.log(e))
          })
        })
      })

      async.series(series, function (error, results) {
        console.log(error, results);
      })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

And this is the front view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="loading-container">
          <img src="/images/logo.png" />
          <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The cycle should be something like: The user is directed to the page / app where he sees a loading icon, the app retrieves a JWT from the params and after decoding it, makes a number of 'POST' calls to a specific endpoint. After the last call is made, the app should redirect the user to another, external, url (ex: https://www.google.com/).

The problem I'm facing is that I can't both use res.render() (to serve the frontal loading page) and res.redirect() (to redirect the user away after all the 'POST' calls are done). How would one go about doing this concept in NodeJS?

Comment: wouldn't your front end make the calls, and then upon success redirect to the given url from the backend?

Comment: Yeah, as @Icepickle said, just have the frontend do the redirect with some javascript

Comment: `res.redirect()` does not do what you think it does. It is a server-side method. You think it's going to instruct the browser to navigate to another site, that's not at all what it does. The browser needs to do this itself. In Node.js, `res.redirect()` calls another route of your Node router.